# Updating one of several views with event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I don't undertand mechanism of events in actionscript completely, so please forgive if a question is dump. Supose that we have a `Controller` (extends `EventDispatcher`) and several views, note that views can be instances of various classes. Supose that each view listens `CustomEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED`. The question is if I do `dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED))` in `Controller`, will event come to each of listeners or it will be caught by first of views and will not go further.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be passed to all listeners until one of them calls the stopImmediatePropagation method of the event object (this will only stop the event if it is cancelable)

Comment: I don't think this answer is specific and thorough enough.

Comment: In your answer nearby, you are talking about only display object tree. But every class can be EventDispatcher if it is derived from EventDispatcher or if it implements IEventDispatcher. And you missed "capture phase". So, your answer is specific too. That is why I didn't show an example - it is too big part of flash api for one answer.

Comment: Yeah, he is asking about view(display) objects capturing events from another object. My answer shows what is possible and in that case. As you could see from my example, a dispatched event will not be passed to all listeners unless they are parents of the dispatcher. I simply think your answer is incorrect. I changed my answer to reflect the Target phase.

Comment: So, as I understand his question: what is the principle of eventdispatcher loop? Because "does system provide it further or not" - is main difference for the languages and systems (java, c++ framworks and so on). And I had similar question some years ago, and I needed answer like mine.

Comment: It doesn't make sense: eventdispatcher can listen itself. I'm talking about basic principle of loop inside of eventdispatcher implementation in flash api. For example, in some systems you should return boolean if event was processed or not. And so on.

Comment: Could you give an example, I'm starting to think you are right, I still feel that if I did not understand your answer, it is possible that a few others may not understand it as well, could be a lot better if you provide an example explaining it in more detail. thanks

Comment: It was many years ago, I used to work with some java framework and in event listeners I had to return boolean if listener process this event and I don't want to pass it further. In Android some UI listeners uses the same methods, as I've understood. So, for me: this is the key difference: what I should do to control event processing? (thanks for grammar correction)

Comment: I understand your example. I have another question, when i gave the example of controllerName.addEventListener(... , ..); you said it did not make sense cause a dispatcher cannot listen to itself. If you look at my code example and run it, you will see (stranger) is an event dispatcher that listens to itself, it works. How do you set up a listener for an event unless it's a dispatcher (listening to itself) or a displayObject listening to it's child?

Comment: hmm... I said "eventdispatcher _can_ listen itself, so it doesn't matter what the target of subsсriber. And the example of when listener and dispatcher is the same object: when you created some class, but you want to make its api replacable without inheritance. So, you can make events and this will allow your system subscribe on these events with highest priority - to change the logic, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For any object to observe an event dispatched by another object, there are several conditions:

1. The object has to be a display object.
2. The object dispatching that event has to be a child of the listening object.
3. If the parent object is listening for the bubbling phase(default), then bubbling has to be set to true during event creation.

   ```
           dispatchEvent(new Event(TYPE_NAME, true));
   ```
4. Otherwise it could be captured in the Capture phase, add event listener with 'useCapture = true to accomplish this.

   ```
           addEventListener(TYPE_NAME, onFuncName, true);
   ```

In all other cases, an object can only capture events dispatched by the object itself in the target phase.

Here is a code example:

```
package regression 
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.EventPhase;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author ...
     */
    public class Check_event_listening_1 extends Sprite
    {
        public  const   EVENT_DANCE     : String    = "dance";
        public  const   EVENT_PLAY      : String    = "play";
        public  const   EVENT_YELL      : String    = "yell";
        private var     baby            : Shape     = new Shape();
        private var     mom             : Sprite    = new Sprite();
        private var     stranger        : EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        public function Check_event_listening_1() 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            trace("test begun");
            addChild(mom);
            mom.addChild(baby);
            stage.addEventListener(EVENT_YELL, onEvent);
            this.addEventListener(EVENT_YELL, onEvent);
            mom.addEventListener(EVENT_YELL, onEvent);
            baby.addEventListener(EVENT_YELL, onEvent);
            stranger.addEventListener(EVENT_YELL, onEvent);
            trace("\nTest1 - Stranger yells with no bubbling");
            stranger.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_YELL, false));
            trace("\nTest2 - Stranger yells with bubbling");
            stranger.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_YELL, true));

            stage.addEventListener(EVENT_PLAY, onEvent);
            this.addEventListener(EVENT_PLAY, onEvent);
            mom.addEventListener(EVENT_PLAY, onEvent);
            baby.addEventListener(EVENT_PLAY, onEvent);
            stranger.addEventListener(EVENT_PLAY, onEvent);
            trace("\nTest3 - baby plays with no bubbling");
            baby.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_PLAY, false));
            trace("\nTest4 - baby plays with bubbling");
            baby.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_PLAY, true));
            trace("\nTest5 - baby plays with bubbling but is not a child of mom");
            mom.removeChild(baby);
            baby.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_PLAY, true));
            mom.addChild(baby);

            stage.addEventListener(EVENT_DANCE, onEvent, true);
            this.addEventListener(EVENT_DANCE, onEvent, true);
            mom.addEventListener(EVENT_DANCE, onEvent, true);
            baby.addEventListener(EVENT_DANCE, onEvent, true);
            trace("\nTest6 - Mom dances without bubbling - everyone is listening during capture phase(not target and bubble phase)");
            mom.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_DANCE, false));
            trace("\nTest7 - Mom dances with bubbling - everyone is listening during capture phase(not target and bubble phase)");
            mom.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_DANCE, true));
        }

        private function onEvent(e : Event):void
        {
            trace("Event was captured");
            trace("\nTYPE : ", e.type, "\nTARGET : ", objToName(e.target), "\nCURRENT TARGET : ", objToName(e.currentTarget), "\nPHASE : ", phaseToString(e.eventPhase));
        }

        private function phaseToString(phase : int):String
        {
            switch(phase)
            {
                case EventPhase.AT_TARGET :
                    return "TARGET";
                case EventPhase.BUBBLING_PHASE :
                    return "BUBBLING";
                case EventPhase.CAPTURING_PHASE :
                    return "CAPTURE";
                default:
                    return "UNKNOWN";
            }

        }

        private function objToName(obj : Object):String
        {
            if (obj == stage) return "STAGE";
            else if (obj == this) return "MAIN";
            else if (obj == mom) return "Mom";
            else if (obj == baby) return "Baby";
            else if (obj == stranger) return "Stranger";
            else return "Unknown"
        }

    }

}
```

I would be glad to shed more light on the subject.